# Materialize collapsible-accordion not working IOS 13

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari, materialize

**My problem**

I am working on a website which is using [materialize sidenav](https://materializecss.com/sidenav.html#!).

When I try to open the collapsible-accordion on my iphone 7 (IOS 13.3.1) in safari it does not work.

But when I try it on a other browser like firefox it works well.

The solution I found on [github](https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/issues/2134) did not work for me.

I have no idea how to fix my problem

Any hep/tips are welcome.

Thanks in advance.

**My code**

```js
function openForm() {
  document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "block";
}

function closeForm() {
  document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "none";
}
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.modal');
    var instances = M.Modal.init(elems);
  });

  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-trigger');
    // var options = 
    var instances = M.Dropdown.init(elems, {coverTrigger: false});
  });
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.sidenav');
    var instances = M.Sidenav.init(elems);
  });
    $(document).ready(function() {
  $('.collapsible').collapsible();
})
```

```css
input:focus {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #1C9CDA !important;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #1C9CDA !important;
}
label.active {
  color: #1C9CDA !important;
}
.standard-bgcolor{
  background-color: #1C9CDA !important;
}
.standard-color{
  color: #1C9CDA !important;
}
.sidenav{
  z-index:1001 !important;
}
.nav{
  padding-left: 16px !important;
}
body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
* {box-sizing: border-box;}
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
#map{
    height:100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.dropdown-content{
   width: max-content !important;
   height:auto !important;
}
/* Button used to open the contact form - fixed at the bottom of the page */
.open-button {
  position: absolute !important;
  bottom: 23px;
  right: 20px;
  width: 200px;
}
#form_btn{
  float: none;
  clear: both;
}

/* The popup form - hidden by default */
.form-popup {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 15px;
  border: 3px solid #f1f1f1;
  z-index: 9;
  margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}

/* Add styles to the form container */
.form-popup{
  max-width: 400px;
  min-width: 300px;
  width: 25%;
}
/*form box*/
.form-container {
  padding: 20px !important;
  background-color: white;
}
.login{
  display: inline;
  font-size: 30px;
}
.Sign-up, .Sign-up:visited{
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-decoration: underline;
  float: none !important;
  clear: both;
}
#form_full{
  background-color: white;  
  width: 100%;
  height: 60%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  left: 20%;
  opacity: 0.9;
}
#Sign-up{
  font-size: 25px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  height: 50px;
  width: auto;
  position: absolute;
  right: 50%;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.not-a-user{
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #707070;
}
.Cancel{
  font-size: 35px;
  color: #707070;
}
.Sign-up_Cancel{
  font-size: 35px;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
#row_link{
  margin-left:  0;
}
.alert {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: #f44336;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
.closebtn {
  margin-left: 15px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.closebtn:hover {
  color: black;
}
#login_alert{
  top: 0;
}
/*table with gps trackers*/
.Assets{
  width: calc(100% - 100px);
  margin: 0px 50px 0px 50px;
}

.link{
  color: #1a9988;
}
.link:hover{
  color:  #0f7567;
}
/*popup add assets style*/
/* The Modal (background) */
.add_assets {
  left: 0;
  top: 10%;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: auto; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  max-height: none !important;
  padding-bottom: 30px !important;
}
#submit{
  font-size: 25px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  height: 50px;
  width: 20%;
  position: absolute;
  right:30px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
#Cancel_add{
  font-size: 25px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  height: 50px;
  width: 20%;
  position: absolute;
  left:30px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #f44336;
}
.animate {
  -webkit-animation: animatezoom 5s;
  animation: animatezoom 5s
  background-color: #fefefe;
}
/*blockquote*/
.blockquote_white {
  border-left-color: white;
}
/*info_box*/
.info_box{
  height: auto;
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  padding:  0 25px 0 25px;
}
/*routing box*/
.leaflet-routing-alternatives-container, .leaflet-bar{
  display: none;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animatezoom {
  from {-webkit-transform: scale(0)} 
  to {-webkit-transform: scale(1)}
}
  
@keyframes animatezoom {
  from {transform: scale(0)} 
  to {transform: scale(1)}
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .Assets::-webkit-scrollbar {
    z-index:10;
  }
  /*asset table*/
  .Assets{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  }
  #submit, #Cancel_add{
    width: auto;
  }
  .modal-content{
    padding: 0;
  }
  #form_full{
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
  }
  #Sign-up{
    width: auto;
    right: 10px;
  }
  .Cancel{
    margin-left: 10px;
  }
  #e-mail, #password, #name , #GPS_ID, #info{
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<ul id="dropdown1" class="dropdown-content">
    <li><a title="Add Asset" class="modal-trigger grey-text text-darken-1" href="#modal1"><i class="material-icons">add</i>Voeg asset toe</a></li>
    <li><a title="Edit profile" class="modal-trigger grey-text text-darken-1" href="#modal2"><i class="material-icons left ">person</i>Edit profile</a></li>
</ul>
 <ul class="sidenav" id="mobile-demo">
  <li class="sidenav-header standard-bgcolor ">
        <div class="row">
         <div class="col s4">
             <h4 class="white-text">Asset tracking</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li> 
    <li class="no-padding nav">
     <ul class="collapsible collapsible-accordion">
      <li>
         <a class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons left">home</i>Home<i class="material-icons right">arrow_drop_down</i></a>
      <div class="collapsible-body">
              <ul>
            <li><a title="Add Asset" class="modal-trigger grey-text text-darken-1" href="#modal1"><i class="material-icons">add</i>Voeg asset toe</a></li>
         <li><a title="Edit profile" class="modal-trigger grey-text text-darken-1" href="#modal2"><i class="material-icons left ">person</i>Edit profile</a></li>
        </ul>
          </div>
         </li>
     </ul>
 </li>
 <li><a class="nav" title="Map" href="index.php"><i class="material-icons">map</i>Kaart</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav" title="Uitloggen" href="?logout=1"><i class="material-icons left">exit_to_app</i>Uitloggen</a></li>   
  </ul>
  <nav>
    <div class="nav-wrapper standard-bgcolor">
     <a href="#" data-target="mobile-demo" class="sidenav-trigger"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
     <a href="#" class="brand-logo center">Asset Tracking</a>
      <ul id="nav-mobile" class="left hide-on-med-and-down">
  <li class="active"><a title="Home" class="dropdown-trigger" data-target="dropdown1" href="#!"><i class="material-icons left">home</i>Home<i class="material-icons right">arrow_drop_down</i></a></li>
       <li><a title="Map" href="index.php"><i class="material-icons left">map</i>Kaart</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
        <li class="right"><a title="Uitloggen" href="?logout=1"><i class="material-icons right">exit_to_app</i>Uitloggen</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div> 
  </nav>
<body>
<!-- add asset form -->
 <div id="modal1" class="modal add_assets modal2">
   <div class="modal-content">
    <h4 class="standard-color">Voeg asset toe</h4>
    <form class="col s12 animate" action="" method="post">
      <div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s12" id="name">
     <input class="validate" type="text" required name="name">
             <label for="Name">Asset name</label>
             <span class="helper-text" data-error="Veld mag niet leeg zijn" data-success="correct">Geef de GPS tracker een naam</span>
    </div>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s12" id="activatiecode">
     <input class="validate" type="text" required name="activatiecode">
             <label for="activatiecode">Activatiecode</label>
             <span class="helper-text" data-error="Moet uniek zijn" data-success="correct">Activatiecode van de tracker (IMEI + korte activatie string)</span>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s12" id="info">
     <input class="validate" type="text" required name="info">
             <label for="Info">Other gps info</label>
             <span data-error="Veld mag niet leeg zijn" data-success="correct" class="helper-text">Extra info over de GPS</span>
    </div>
   </div>
       <div class="input-group">
         <button id="submit" class="btn waves-effect standard-bgcolor" type="submit" name="submit">Add</button>
      </div>
         <button id="Cancel_add" type="button" class="btn waves-effect  modal-close" >Cancel</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
 </div>
  <!-- Update profile form -->
 <div id="modal2" class="modal add_assets modal2">
   <div class="modal-content">
    <h4 class="standard-color">Update account</h4>
    <form class="col s12 animate" action="" method="post">
      <div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s12" id="name">
     <input value="<?=$email?>" class="validate" type="email" required name="email">
             <label for="Name">E-mail Address</label>
             <span class="helper-text" data-error="Geen correct e-mailadres" data-success="correct">voorbeeld@voorbeeld.nl</span>
    </div>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s12" id="password">
     <input minlength="10" required type="password" class="validate" name="password_1">
           <label for="Password">Password</label>
           <span class="helper-text" data-error="Wachtwoord is te kort" data-success="correct">10 karakters lang</span>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s12" id="password">
     <input minlength="10" required type="password" class="validate" name="password_2">
           <label for="Password">Confrim password</label>
           <span class="helper-text" data-error="Wachtwoord is te kort" data-success="correct">10 karakters lang</span>
    </div>
   </div>
       <div class="input-group">
         <button id="submit" class="btn waves-effect standard-bgcolor" type="submit" name="update">Update</button>
      </div>
         <button id="Cancel_add" type="button" class="btn waves-effect  modal-close">Cancel</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok for a start your JS is not properly formatted. You have 4 separate document-ready functions, and a mix of vanilla JS and jQuery inits. Choose 1 and stick with it. You just need one document ready, then all the code that needs to wait until the dom is loaded sits inside.

```
function openForm() {
  document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "block";
}

function closeForm() {
  document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "none";
}
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.modal');
    var instances = M.Modal.init(elems);
  });

  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-trigger');
    // var options = 
    var instances = M.Dropdown.init(elems, {coverTrigger: false});
  });
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.sidenav');
    var instances = M.Sidenav.init(elems);
  });
    $(document).ready(function() {
  $('.collapsible').collapsible();
})
```

I have tidied that up and put your code into a codepen, and it is working perfectly fine for me (iPhone XR 13.3.1 Safari). Can you text this?

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

    var modals = document.querySelectorAll('.modal');
    var modal = M.Modal.init(modals);

    var triggers = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-trigger');
    var trigger = M.Dropdown.init(triggers, {coverTrigger: false});

    var sidenavs = document.querySelectorAll('.sidenav');
    var sidenav = M.Sidenav.init(sidenavs);

    $('.collapsible').collapsible();

  });
```

https://codepen.io/doughballs/pen/QWbQPew